# How to set margin on print page when there are table break CSS applied

Tags: javascript, css, print-css

I am having a weird issue on print css, when I set a css for table break according to page height,it is working perfectly,

```
@page { size: A4; margin: 23mm 10mm 20mm 10mm; }
@media print {  body{} table{ page-break-inside:auto !important ;}
 tr{ page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto ;}
 td{ page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto ;}
thead { display:table-header-group; }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group; }}
```

with `margin:0` top of the page have no space, now if I add `margin: 20mm 10mm 20mm 10mm`to the `@page` section it does the spaces on page but the table break-up does not working now, I have put `margin and padding` in the `body` css also, but no luck yet, already wasted a day, please give me any idea how could I do this.

Comment: Please update with the html codes.

Comment: the html code is dynamic, user can print any type of content, actually I made the table break up css for one user request..

Comment: Show your html with a fiddle. That will be really helpful to understand what is breaking. A sample table with css applied to it.